# It is ok to use varchar(32) for md5 hash

Tags: php, sql

Just a simple question I am using  `varchar(50) NOT NULL,` for md5 hash code

Just want to know if its ok to use it as 32?

Another thing i have millions of md5 hash code as far they dont match with other, is there a cash that two different **keyword** can have same md5 hash?

Thanks

Comment: You know the `MD5` produces 32 characters, so `VARCHAR(32)` or `CHAR(32)` will do just fine.

Comment: Read the wikipedia articles on MD5 and the Birthday Paradox to get an idea of collision chances.

Comment: Thanks for answer just wanted to make it sure. @JW웃 AND BoltClock

Comment: different **keyword** will have different **hash**.

Comment: uhh `32^16 = 120,892,581,961,462,917,4706,176`, so @BoltClock: as long as he's generating hashes properly, there shouldn't be any collisions. I would also recommend that OP place `UNIQUE` on the column.

Comment: yes i am using it as unique and if they match i get notify for fault :) @DavidChen

Comment: What are you calculating the hash with, if it's user input -- there's a chance that you might get a collision, if it's just for sessions then you're fine.

Comment: $keyword = md5($userid . $blabla . $blabla . $blabla . $user_email); $blabla is different values and values may match one or two but cant match all thee  @DavidChen

Comment: its totally a different keyword :)

Comment: userid auto increment and email is different

Comment: There's still always a chance for collisions, no matter how big or small the keyspace. @DavidChen An MD5 hash has 2^128 possible values, but if you're really really unlucky you may find the two values that produce the same hash on the first try. That's very very very very unlikely, but nonetheless possible.

Comment: i checked till 3 millions only and so far no match :) may be i am lucky lol @deceze

Comment: @deceze: I didn't completely rule out of 0% chance, you should always check with your database before inserting.

Comment: @DaveChen, I think you meant to say, "set a UNIQUE index on the column".  What's the point in running a `SELECT` to see if the hash is in the table already?  By the time you `INSERT`, it may be there.  Again, this is incredibly unlikely though, and you take a large performance hit for such an index.

Comment: I mean set unique constrict on the column.

Comment: @deerox I have given an example of a hash collision in my answer, and a link which explains the collision, if you're interested in gaining a better understanding of message digest functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VARCHAR` is for strings where you don't know the length, you trade off a lesser performance for a greater flexibility. As you know the field will be 32 characters long, you should use `CHAR(32)` (which expects **exactly** 32 characters) instead.

As for collision possibility: yes, `MD5` hashes can be identical. An easy way to test this for yourself is to `md5sum` a 33-character hexadecimal number. If this works, you know that there are more possible inputs than outputs, so two inputs **must** be able to map to the same output.

These two blocks (courtesy of [this link](http://www.mscs.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/)) famously both give an `md5sum` of `79054025255fb1a26e4bc422aef54eb4`:

```
BLOCK 1:
d131dd02c5e6eec4693d9a0698aff95c 2fcab58712467eab4004583eb8fb7f89
55ad340609f4b30283e488832571415a 085125e8f7cdc99fd91dbdf280373c5b
d8823e3156348f5bae6dacd436c919c6 dd53e2b487da03fd02396306d248cda0
e99f33420f577ee8ce54b67080a80d1e c69821bcb6a8839396f9652b6ff72a70

BLOCK 2:
d131dd02c5e6eec4693d9a0698aff95c 2fcab50712467eab4004583eb8fb7f89
55ad340609f4b30283e4888325f1415a 085125e8f7cdc99fd91dbd7280373c5b
d8823e3156348f5bae6dacd436c919c6 dd53e23487da03fd02396306d248cda0
e99f33420f577ee8ce54b67080280d1e c69821bcb6a8839396f965ab6ff72a70
```

[This website](http://www.links.org/?p=6) provides a visualization into **why** those particular strings collide, if you're interested (it's quite technical but very interesting if you want to better understand message digest and hashing).

Answer (score 2):

Since you are dealing with a specific size, use `char(32)` for better performance.

`varchar` requires an extra couple of bytes to store the length of the string.  No need, because you already know the length.